# Steam games not working for linux

Tags: games, steam, chromebook, chromeos

So i was downloading steam on my Chromebook when i finished downloading everything i launched a game, immediately it crashed and i think it has something to do with this text :

OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.

For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9938-EYZB-7457.

please help :(, i just need to find out how to fix this issue, i am also new, i don't understand much about coding etc

Comment: http://www.dudleymediagroup.com/Detail/id/how-to-game-with-steam-on-a-google-chromebook-2335
explains how.
Notice the warning about it not working on ARM devices. Perhaps you should post the specs of your Chromebook...

Comment: Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)
Platform 8350.68.0 (Official Build) stable-channel glimmer
Firmware Google_Glimmer.5216.198.19

Comment: My chromebook isnt arm it's intel based, this problem has been bugging me for really long